# Why is this rotating animation moving vertically?

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am trying to implement a Loader that rotates in the center of the screen:

```
struct Loader : View {
    
    @State var isRotated = false
    var animation: Animation {
        Animation.linear
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.8)
                .stroke(AngularGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9069682956, green: 0.7839415669, blue: 0.9612388015, alpha: 1)),.white]), center: .center), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8, lineCap: .round))
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(isRotated ? 360 : 0))
                .animation(animation)
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.isRotated.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I want the loader to rotate in the middle of the screen, but when I run my code the circle moves up the y axis with each rotation. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Does changing `.animation(animation)` to `.animation(animation, value: isRotated)` help?

Comment: yes that fixed it! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

this should solve

```
.onAppear{
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.isRotated.toggle()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be happier using [`TimelineView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview), which lets you eliminate the use of `@State`, `animation`, and `onAppear`:

```
struct Loader : View {    
    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.animation) { context in
            let period = 1.0 // seconds per full rotation
            let degrees = context.date
                .timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                .remainder(dividingBy: period) * 360 / period
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.8)
                .stroke(
                    AngularGradient(
                        gradient: .init(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9069682956, green: 0.7839415669, blue: 0.9612388015, alpha: 1)), .white]),
                        center: .center
                    ),
                    style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8, lineCap: .round)
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(degrees))
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
        }
    }
}
```